# array_map applied on a function with 2 parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I've 2 arrays (`$numbers` and `$letters`) and I want to create a new array based on a function that combines every `$numbers` with every `$letters`. The parameters of this function involes the value of both `$numbers` and `$letters`. *(Note: $numbers and $letters doesn't have the same amount of values)*. I need something like this:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,...);
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e',...);

function myFunction($x,$y){
     // $output = some code that use $x and $y
     return $output;
};

$array_1 = array( (myFunction($numbers[0],$letters[0])), (myFunction($numbers[0],$letters[1])), myFunction($numbers[0],$letters[2]), myFunction($numbers[0],$letters[3]), etc);

$array_2 = array( (myFunction($numbers[1],$letters[0])), (myFunction($numbers[1],$letters[1])), myFunction($numbers[1],$letters[2]), myFunction($numbers[1],$letters[3]), etc);

$array_3 = array( (myFunction($numbers[2],$letters[0])), (myFunction($numbers[2],$letters[1])), myFunction($numbers[2],$letters[2]), myFunction($numbers[2],$letters[3]), etc);

...

$array_N = array( (myFunction($numbers[N],$letters[0])), (myFunction($numbers[N],$letters[1])), myFunction($numbers[N],$letters[2]), myFunction($numbers[N],$letters[3]), etc);

$array = array($array_1, $array_2, $array_3, etc.);
```

I know that this may work, but it's a lot of code, especially if I have a many values for each array. Is there a way to get the same result with less code? I tried this, but it's not working:

```
$array = array_map("myFunction($value, $letters)",$numbers));
```

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a bunch of ways to go about this problem, but for readability/maintainability, I would simply use a couple loops:

```
$array = array();

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $row = array();

    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        $row[] = myFunction($number, $letter);
    }

    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tested your suggestion but I get `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context` --> refering to `$row() = myFunction($number, $letter);`

Comment: @mat: I didn't write `$row()`, I wrote `$row[]`.  Square brackets, not parentheses.  Same goes for `$array[]`.

Comment: If I use square brackets I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: @mat: I can't help without seeing your code.  Edit your question and paste the code, or paste it [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) and give me the relevant URL.

Comment: @mat: Line 8 is `$array = [];` which tells me that you aren't using PHP 5.4 yet, so you'll need to use the old array initialization syntax.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I've one last doubt, what should I change if I want to get each arrey sparately (`$array_1`, `$array_2`, `$array_3`, ..., `$array_N`) instead of the multidimensional array `$array`?

Comment: @mat: Just use the numeric index.  The first array in the collection will have index `0`, the second will have index `1`, and so on.  So to access the 3rd array, you would just use `$array[2]` (which would have the same data in it as `$array_3` from your example).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `array_map`:

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e');

$result = array_map(function($n) use ($letters) {
    return array_map(function($l) use ($n) {
         return myFunction($n, $l);
    }, $letters);
}, $numbers);
```

***[Here is the demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/g972sf)***